# Suppose that in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ that for $a \in \Bbb Z_p^*$, $o(a)=m$, show that for any integer $k$, that $o(a^k)=\frac {m} {gcd(m,k)}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ that for $a \in \Bbb Z_p^*$, $o(a)=m$, then I wish to show that for any integer $k \geq1$, that $o(a^k)=\frac {m} {gcd(m,k)}$.

So if $d=gcd(m,k)$, then $a^{k^{m/d}}=a^{m^{k/d}}=1$. Now to show that $\frac {m} {gcd(m,k)}$ is the smallest such integer is where I am stuck. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $k/d$ where you wrote $d/k$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes typo, edited.

Comment: If $(a^k)^e=1$ with $0<e<\frac md$ then ....

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm guessing either the $o(a)=m$ gets contradicted?

Comment: This formula holds in all groups, not just $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$. Commonly it is encountered in the first course where cyclic groups and their subgroups are studied.